# Use htaccess to allow POST, but block browsing PHP files

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a directory with PHP files I do not want anonymous users to view or bots to index. However, I do want anonymous HTTP POST request-resposes to the PHP files to work (i.e. from other PHP forms on various websites).

Will it be this?

```
<Limit POST GET>
allow from all
</Limit>
<files "*.php">
deny from all
</files>
```

My PHP script processes posted data and then performs a POST to another web-service. Will the .htaccess block post-response communications from the protected PHP script?

Comment: You want to allow anonymous requests, but you also don't want to allow anonymous requests? <scratches head> :-S

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to move the PHP file responsible for the transmission into different directory, and then safeguard the other directory with simple htaccess directive forbidding to view all files?

Comment: I'm guessing you don't want people to see your raw PHP code? Is that it?

Comment: Yes, I do not want my php code to be viewed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. PHP can't be viewed from outside. At all. The only way to see PHP code is to somehow gain access to the computer on which it is held: this is because PHP is parsed and executed by the server to generate the HTML which is shown to the client. In other words, as long as someone has not hacked into your actual server computer, they can't see your PHP.

Comment: Oh! Well it sound like I'm safe. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do that with an .htaccess file (you probably can, but I've never done it...), but if you have publicly accessible php files that you only want to post to, you can use something like this in every script:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
{
  // post request, do your stuff
}
else
{
  // not a post request, redirect, show error message, etc.
}
```

Comment: I'll have to investigate this interesting option. Thanks.